# Set the current date in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I'm currently working on my company's in-house CMS and wish to add the ability for an admin to view the site on a specific date. This will allow admins to preview the site with archived or scheduled posts.

I'd like to avoid finding all mentions of `date()` or `time()` and offsetting them. Is there a way of making PHP *think* it's a specific date so that all calls to `date()` default to the new time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an encapsulation issue -- why not search for all mentions of `date()` or `time()` and replace them with `$site->getDisplayedDate()`, or something else appropriate to your code?

Comment: I know I could do this, but I'd still be interested to know whether what I've asked is doable. I'm working with some legacy code and I'm afraid it's not the best-structured work I've come across :(

Comment: I feel your pain, but I don't think there's any way to do this. Think about it this way... how would you feel if, in some unrelated code, you called `time()` and it gave you some date 3 weeks in the future?

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the answer anyway, I'm happy to do it this way if there's no alternative! No OOP though, all globals :(

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of changing it globally, which would change the date for everyone on the server at that point.

I would probably store a timestamp in the session or similar, so that it can be easily changed and updated at will, rather than changing core php ini values.

[You might try this though](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)